# JPA Criteria OR condition on related entity with path navigation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have the following entity structure

```
public class Application {
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Account account;

    @JoinColumn(name = "involved_account_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Account involvedAccount;
}

public class Account {
    private string id;
    private string name;
}
```

I want to get all the applications where `account` name or `involvedAccount` name matching a given account name.

```
CriteriaQuery<Application> query = cb.createQuery(Application.class);
Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);

Predicate conditions = cb.conjunction();

conditions = cb.and(conditions, cb.or(
    cb.like(
        cb.upper(root.get("account").get("name")), 
        accountName.toUpperCase()
    ), cb.like(
        cb.upper(root.get("involvedAccount").get("name")), 
        accountName.toUpperCase())
    )
);

query.where(conditions);
query.select(root);
```

But the above produces the following where condition where it uses `and` for primary keys rather than `or`

```
where applicati0_.account_id=account1_.id
    and applicati0_.involved_account_id=account2_.id
    and 1=1
    and (
        upper(account1_.name) like ?
        or upper(account2_.id) like ?
    )
```

This is where the condition fails as the expression 
`applicati0_.account_id=account1_.id and applicati0_.involved_account_id=account2_.id` uses `and` instead of `or`

Comment: You have used `@JoinColumn`, that's why the 2 `and` conditions are added. Can you post your entire query? Also, can you please specify your expected output?

Comment: I want it to be `or` instead of `and`. i.e `applicati0_.account_id=account1_.id
    or applicati0_.involved_account_id=account2_.id`

Comment: The SQL query is correct. You want account1 to be the application's account and account2 to be the application's involved account. And you want account1's name or account2's name to be like the given string.

Comment: @JBNizet But the result only includes applications where it matches with involved account. involved account is null on some applications. Those are not returned

Comment: Then you shouldn't use an inner join (i.e. root.get("account")), but you should instead use a left join. I strongly suggest you use a JPQL query instead of a criteria query. It would be much clearer. Criteria queries are for dynamic queries, not static ones.

Comment: Adding to what @JBNizet said, I think even native SQL Query will solve your requirement. I don't know why you are using CriteriaQuery.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya don't make me say something I never said. I didn't recommend using a native query. I recommended using a JPQL query.

Comment: Sorry. Edited @JBNizet

Comment: @JBNizet I'm working on a legacy project and the above only includes partial of original code. I have to add an expression to the query which is dynamically generated. is there anyway to use left join with criteria query. I'll look into JPQL

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join-javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute-javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType-

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join-javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute-javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType-), as suggested in the comments.

I can't test right now, but something like this should work:

```
CriteriaQuery<Application> query = cb.createQuery(Application.class);
Root<Application> root = query.from(Application.class);
Join<Application, Account> account = root.join("account");
Join<Application, Account> involvedAccount = root.join("involvedAccount");

Predicate conditions = cb.conjunction();

conditions = cb.and(conditions, cb.or(
    cb.like(
        cb.upper(account.get("name")), 
        accountName.toUpperCase()
    ), cb.like(
        cb.upper(involvedAccount.get("name")), 
        accountName.toUpperCase())
    )
);

query.where(conditions);
query.select(root);
```